# Multiple Delete/Update using php- Codeigniter Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

The console.log(response) returns the code of whole page in console when I inspect it in ajax . I have created a codeigniter project with MySQL as back end database . I have fetched content from table from database into table. Now I want to give option to user of mulitple delete. Please take it into account that I am not actually deleting value from table I am just turning status of of that row to inactive. It goes as :

> If status= 0 : the row's data will be visible in table.
>   If status= 1:the row's data will not be visible in table.

I have given checkbox option in the table to select multiple checkbox.

Here is my javascript:

To check all the check boxes:-

```
<script language="JavaScript">
            function selectAll(source) {
                checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('sport');
                for(var i in checkboxes)
                    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        </script>
```

javascript to get value's from the checkboxes and send it to controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

               function okay(){
                    var favorite = [];
                    $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function(){            
                        favorite.push($(this).val());

                        var txt=$(this).val();

                    });



                      for (var i = 0;i<favorite.length;i++) {

                            $.ajax({
                                url:('<?=base_url()?>/Repots/supervisor_muldel'),
                                type:'POST',
                                data:{'value_id':favorite[i]},
                                success:function(response)
                                {
                                  console.log(response);
                                },
                                error:function(response)
                                {
                                    console.log('nahi gaya');
                                },

                            }); 
                            //console.log(favorite[i]);

                        }

                    //alert("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));
            }

        </script>
```

every check box is associate with particular values.
here the html button to call the fucntion:

```
 <button onclick="okay();">Delete Selected</button>
```

**Controller:Reports/supervisor_muldel**:

```
//multiple delete supervisor

public function supervisor_muldel() {

$value_id = $this->input->post('value_id');
$selected_supervisor = array('supervisor_id' =>$value_id);
$staus=array('status'=>1);


$this->load->model('Entry_model');
$result = $this->Entry_model->supervisor_muldel($staus,$selected_supervisor);

}
```

**Entry_model/supervisor_muldel:**
//delete multiple supervisor

```
 public function supervisor_muldel($staus,$condition)
    {

        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->where($condition)
                 ->update('tbl_supervisor',$staus);

        $this->db->trans_complete();

    }
```

The console.log returns the code of whole page in console.I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put wrong ajax request URL.
Change

```
url:('<?=base_url()?>/Repots/supervisor_muldel'),
```

to

```
url:('<?=base_url()?>/Reports/supervisor_muldel'),
```

Look at the controller name in URL.

Comment: So silly mistake , I have updated my code it works fine, Thank You very much.